# Making a matrix that counts the number of companies that were rating i in 1996 and moved to rating j in 1997 and rating k in 1998

Tags: r, matrix, markov-chains

I'm trying to make a matrix using a function that counts the number of "ID"s that were in "RATING" i in "YEAR" 1996 and then moved to "RATING" k in "YEAR" 1997 and then moved to "RATING" k in "YEAR" 1998.

I believe the row labels of the matrix would be the combinations of "RATING" i & "RATING" j and the column labels of the matrix would be the "RATING" k.

The sum of each row should be the sum of all "ID"s that were "RATING" i in 1996  and "RATING" k in 1997.

This is my sample data.

```
df <- rbind(df, data.frame("ID"=c('6387', '6387', '6387', '6403', '6403', '6403', '6408', '6408', '6408', '6411', '6411', '6411', '6413', '6413', '6413', '6422', '6422', '6422', '6427', '6427', '6427')))
df <- cbind(df, data.frame("YEAR"=c('1996', '1997', '1998', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1996', '1997', '1998')))
df <- cbind(df, data.frame("RATING"=c('Aa', 'Ba', 'Ba', 'B', 'Caa', 'Caa', 'A', 'Ba', 'Ba', 'B', 'Ba', 'B', 'B', 'Caa', 'Caa', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'Caa', 'B', 'Caa')))
```

Using the code provided by @Muffindorf :

```
df_long <- spread(df, YEAR, RATING)
df_long$c9697 <- paste(df_long$`1996`, df_long$`1997`, sep = '-')
as.matrix(table(df_long$c9697, df_long$`1998`))
```

gives me:

```
       A Aa B Ba Caa
 A-Ba  0  0 0  1   0
 Aa-Ba 0  0 0  1   0
 B-B   0  0 1  0   0
 B-Ba  0  0 1  0   0
 B-Caa 0  0 0  0   2
 Caa-B 0  0 0  0   1
```

The row labels tell us the previous ratings in 1996 and 1997, the column labels tell us the rating in 1998, and the elements tell us the count of IDs that followed the transitions.

What I need to do now is have my row labels be all the possible combinations of ratings, unobserved included. The code above only results in row labels of observed combinations.

Comment: What is the original `df` in the example

Comment: df <- data.frame()

Comment: It's an empty dataframe.

Comment: What is your expected output? It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to construct a second order Markov Chain. The matrix represents the count of "ID"s in 1998 rated k conditional on their rating in 1997 and 1996.

Comment: That doesn't help. Please show what the output would look like using the example data you provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyr)

df_long <- spread(df, YEAR, RATING)

df_long$c9697 <- paste(df_long$`1996`, df_long$`1997`, sep = '-')

as.matrix(table(df_long$c9697, df_long$`1998`))
```

Granted, this does not have all the combinations of ratings, but I guess you can add them manually

Comment: Thank you! This is very close. What is the most efficient way of adding all the combinations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020826/how-do-you-map-every-combination-of-categorical-variables-in-r